# Read_Table with multiple comment characters

Tags: pandas

I have data that is in 4 columns with a # separating comments at the end of the row.  That's easy to read just the 4 columns and ignore the comment using the comment='#' in read_table.

However, there is a line separating years of data.  It is 8 '-' with nothing else on the line.  I want skip the whole line that starts '--'.

It's easy to write a python preprocessor that removes that line but how can I have pandas read_table function skip those lines?   I can skip headers and footers in the data but not non-blank separator lines.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Post raw input data, thanks, one thing to try is to pass a list to comments so `comments=['#','--']`

Comment: I had tried a list of strings for comments before writing.  It was rejected.  I believe comments must be a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Ii would just say to let them in and then to drop rows that have `--` in the first column. Something like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('in.txt',sep=',',header=0,names=['A','B','C','D'])

In [3]: print df
          A     B   C            D
0         q    88  46   19#comment
1  --------   NaN NaN          NaN
2         s   534  16          444
3         q  8138  46  19#comment2
4     --12q    54  17           16

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('in.txt',sep=',',header=0,names=['A','B','C','D'],comment='#')

In [5]: print df
          A     B   C    D
0         q    88  46   19
1  --------   NaN NaN  NaN
2         s   534  16  444
3         q  8138  46   19
4     --12q    54  17   16

In [6]: df2 = df[~df['A'].str.contains("--")]

In [7]: print df2
   A     B   C    D
0  q    88  46   19
2  s   534  16  444
3  q  8138  46   19
```

Comment: That works but only if I remove the parameter 'index_col=0' from the read_table function.  Thanks.

Comment: See the docs for boolean indexing on using the tilde ~ for inverting your selection. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing